# How to find SQL Server name in logging in to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I create a server name for database engine in logging in to SQL Server Management Studio?

Or how can I find my default server name? I have been using running `SQLCMD -L` this code in my command prompt but it turns me nothing it just says `Servers:`

Comment: try using `localhost` or `.` to connect to a local instance

Comment: i got login now thanks @CrApHeR. the problem now is i can't import my database with an extension of .mdf. how can i export it? so i wont create another one?

Comment: If my comment solve your problem, I'll post it as an answer. About your second question, you have attach the db. (Right click on your server Attach Database)

Comment: thanks @CrApHeR you may post it as an answer. that is what i am looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `Localhost` or `.` to connect to your local instance.

Also, to reattach your database (from the mdf file), you can use the Attach Database command that is showed in the following image.

[image: Attach Database]

Hope this helps